# Laravel - dumping october CMS - class log/request/... not found

Tags: php, laravel, containers, octobercms

We have a large app built on `Laravel 5.1` and `October CMS`. Right now we are trying to get rid of october, but we are facing some problems. We managed to remove all october's dependencies, including those in `Application`, but there is something strange going on.

When I try to run the app, i.e. run `php artisan tinker` I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:741
    Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(741): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(842): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(775): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/ in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 741
```

I searched the net for this error and most of the suggested reasons are some sort of error in config files. But I checked them all, in fact I even tried to comment out all of the config files and I still get the same error.

I tried to resolve this dependency manually, by adding the following line in `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->bind('log',\Illuminate\Log\Writer::class);
```

but then I get following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:690
```

I tried to replace exception handler in `App\Exceptions\Handler` with a fake one:

```
class FakeHandler implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler
{
    public function renderForConsole($output, Exception $e)
    {
        print_r($e);
    }

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        print_r($e);
    }

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        print_r($e);
    }
}
```

but this only got me one step further - I got rid of `log` dependency, but it failed on resolving `request` alias:

```
ReflectionException: Class request does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 741
```

My main suspicion is that aliases/dependencies defined in `Illuminate\Foundation\Application@registerCoreContainerAliases()` are not being resolved properly.

```
$aliases = [
            'app'                  => ['Illuminate\Foundation\Application', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application'],
            'auth'                 => 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager',
            'auth.driver'          => ['Illuminate\Auth\Guard', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard'],
            'auth.password.tokens' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\TokenRepositoryInterface',
            'blade.compiler'       => 'Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler',
            'cache'                => ['Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory'],
            'cache.store'          => ['Illuminate\Cache\Repository', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository'],
            'config'               => ['Illuminate\Config\Repository', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository'],
            'cookie'               => ['Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Cookie\Factory', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Cookie\QueueingFactory'],
            'encrypter'            => ['Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter'],
            'db'                   => 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager',
            'db.connection'        => ['Illuminate\Database\Connection', 'Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface'],
            'events'               => ['Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher'],
            'files'                => 'Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem',
            'filesystem'           => ['Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory'],
            'filesystem.disk'      => 'Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem',
            'filesystem.cloud'     => 'Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Cloud',
            'hash'                 => 'Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher',
            'translator'           => ['Illuminate\Translation\Translator', 'Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface'],
            'log'                  => ['Illuminate\Log\Writer', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Logging\Log', 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface'],
            'mailer'               => ['Illuminate\Mail\Mailer', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue'],
            'auth.password'        => ['Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker'],
            'queue'                => ['Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Factory', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Monitor'],
            'queue.connection'     => 'Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue',
            'redirect'             => 'Illuminate\Routing\Redirector',
            'redis'                => ['Illuminate\Redis\Database', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Redis\Database'],
            'request'              => 'Illuminate\Http\Request',
            'router'               => ['Illuminate\Routing\Router', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Registrar'],
            'session'              => 'Illuminate\Session\SessionManager',
            'session.store'        => ['Illuminate\Session\Store', 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface'],
            'url'                  => ['Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator'],
            'validator'            => ['Illuminate\Validation\Factory', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory'],
            'view'                 => ['Illuminate\View\Factory', 'Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory'],
```

How can I fix it/check if they are resolved/make them resolve/get rid of october properly/run my application?

Answer (score -1):

it looks like log is removed. try to run

> composer install

with the normal and required depenecies

here the composer.json for laravel 5.1

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Comment: I tried that - with no effect. I also tried to remove `composer.lock` and make a fresh install of all dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Remove unnecessary package dependency from composer.json file then run "composer update".